# Re-use on-premises IP address on VPC?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I'm newbie to AWS.  We're considering to (kind of) make use of AWS for disaster recovery of on-premises workloads (VM and physical machines).   Based on limited knowledge on AWS, I'm thinking of 'cloning' on-premises systems to AWS.   However, our servers and applications use statically hard-coded IP addresses.    Regardless of how the machines are clone to AWS, I wonder if we can 'extend' on-premises VLAN and IP address range to AWS so that we don't  have to change the IP and host based firewall setting.   Can we make VPC network range same as on-premises IP range?   Would someone advise how this can be done, if feasible?

Thanks a lot.
Rgds

Comment: How are you going to connect your internal network to the VPC?  If you have a disaster wouldn't that also take out your other on-premises systems?  In general, no you can't overlap your local IP addresses with an AWS VPC and route properly over DirectConnect or a VPN.

Comment: VPCs have an RFC1918 IPv4 CIDR block which can be 10/8, 172.16/12, or 192.168/16. Are your on-prem systems that are using hard-coded IPs all RFC1918?